# React Native boilerplate files

Tags: react-native

this is my situation:

- new to react native
- familiar with react.js for web
- successfully ran the boilerplate from the react-native cli.

Can someone send me links to docs or articles discussing or explaining the files in the boilerplate?

Which files are safe to delete? I want to make a minimized build as possible and understand the whole ecosystem behind it.

I'm sure react native compiles with babel since it has jsx in it. But how?
I just don't understand yet how react native works. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Please elaborate some more